# How to call one of several Excel sheets in a Workbook to export values to Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a template word document that is using labels to input data from an excel spreadsheet. Due to the nature of my working environment I cannot use MailMerge for this task. The data will always be in the same cells because the admin staff always inputs new data in the third row.

My problem is that the information could be drawn from one of several excel worksheets within the workbook. I could run through a series of MsgBox prompts (as I did in my example code) but that seems inefficient.

Is there any way I can prompt the user to select one of the seven worksheets within that workbook?

My code:

```
Sub Populate()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\")
MSG1 = MsgBox("Is the information found on Sheet 1?", vbYesNo, "Sheet Selection")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then 
 ThisDocument.This.Caption = "Objet/Subject: " & exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3)
 ThisDocument.That.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1)
 ThisDocument.Your.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
Else 
 MSG2 = MsgBox("Is the information found on Sheet 2?", vbYesNo, "Sheet Selection")
End If

If MSG2 = vbYes Then
ThisDocument.This.Caption = "Objet/Subject: " & exWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 3)
 ThisDocument.That.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1)
 ThisDocument.Your.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: A generic input box and then asking them to confirm their input, eg: what worksheet number? You entered X, is this correct?

Comment: @NickSlash 's suggestion is workable. If you want something "fancier" you could create a UserForm with a listbox or combobox that your code fills with the worksheet names. The user selects an entry, confirms the UserForm, and your code procedes from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
foreach(Excel.Worksheet xlworksheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
{
    //find a selected worksheet
    if (xlworksheet.EnableSelection == XlEnableSelection.xlNoRestrictions)
    {

    }
}
```